# Prove or refute $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^{kn}\right)^{\frac{\mu(k)}{k}}=e^{\frac{x}{1-x}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, integer-partitions, mobius-function

I believe that it is possible to combine the identity $(16)$ from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html) related to the Möbius function, with the the generating function for the partition function $p(n)$, see in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) to get $$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^{kn}\right)^{\frac{\mu(k)}{k}}=e^{\frac{x}{1-x}},$$
for $0<x<1$.

I would like to know if my calculations and manipulations were rights, then I can do a comparison between your calculations and reasonings if you provide me those and my calculaitons.

> **Question.** Prove or refute previous identity.

Comment: It is true! Equivalently, $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{\phi\left(n\right)}{n} \log\dfrac{1}{1-x^n} = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$ (here I have taken the logarithm, replaced the $p$-series by its well-known product expression, and simplified a sum using the formula $\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \dfrac{\mu\left(d\right)}{d} = \dfrac{\phi\left(n\right)}{n}$). Which follows from the Mercator series for the logarithm along with the identity $\sum\limits_{n\mid g} \phi\left(n\right) = g$, but is still nice!

Comment: @darijgrinberg: that perfectly fits into an answer, why not to write it as such?

Comment: Will do that soon. (I can actually avoid using the $\phi$-function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed proof based on the ideas in my comments (but without using the $\phi$ function).

We shall work in the ring $\mathbb{Q}\left[  \left[  x\right]  \right]  $ of
power series in one indeterminate $x$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

We shall use the notation $\mathbb{N}$ for $\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $,
and the notation $\mathbb{N}_{+}$ for $\left\{  1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  $.

> **Definition.** For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $p\left(  n\right)  $ be the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the number $n$.
>
> **Theorem 1.** We have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)
> x^{n}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{k}}$.

Theorem 1 is extremely well-known; e.g., it is the first statement in [the
"Generating function" section of the Wikipedia page about
partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function).
I am sure you know it; just writing this for reference's sake.

On the other hand, let us introduce the Möbius function:

> **Definition.** Let $\mu:\mathbb{N}_{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be the map that sends every $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$ to $ \begin{cases} \left(  -1\right)  ^{\omega\left(  n\right)  }, & \text{if }n\text{ is squarefree;}\\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $. Here, $\omega\left(  n\right)  $ denotes the number of all distinct primes dividing $n$.

The function $\mu$ is called the *Möbius function*.

Now, your claim is the following:

> **Theorem 2.** We have $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  x^{kn}\right)  ^{\mu\left(  k\right)  /k} =\exp\dfrac{x}{1-x}$.

We are going to prepare for the proof of this theorem by introducing a few
more notations:

> **Definition.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$. Then, the summation sign $\sum\limits_{d\mid n}$ shall always mean a sum over all positive divisors $d$ of $n$ (rather than a sum over all divisors $d$ of $n$). For example, $\sum\limits_{d\mid2}d$ is $1+2=3$ (not $1+2+\left(  -1\right)  +\left( -2\right)  =0$).
>
> **Definition.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a logical statement. Then, an element $\left[  \mathcal{A}\right]  \in\left\{  0,1\right\}  $ is defined as follows: We set $\left[  \mathcal{A}\right]  = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if }\mathcal{A}\text{ is true};\\ 0, & \text{if }\mathcal{A}\text{ is false} \end{cases} $. This element $\left[  \mathcal{A}\right]  $ is called the *truth value* of $\mathcal{A}$. (For example, $\left[  1+1=2\right]  =1$ and $\left[ 1+1=3\right]  =0$.) The notation $\left[  \mathcal{A}\right]  $ for the truth value of $\mathcal{A}$ is known as the *Iverson bracket notation*.

Now, a well-known fact (see, e.g., Proposition 2.4.7 in [my notes on *Floor and arithmetic functions*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/floor.pdf)) says the following:

> **Theorem 3.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$. Then, $\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \mu\left(  d\right)  =\left[  n=1\right]  $.

(There are many alternative notations for $\left[  n=1\right]  $; for
instance, it can be called $\varepsilon\left(  n\right)  $ or $\delta_{n,1}$.)

Another well-known fact is the following expansion of the logarithm as a power
series (often called the *Mercator series*):

> **Theorem 4.** We have $\log\left(  1-x\right)  =-\sum\limits_{s\geq1} \dfrac{x^{s}}{s}$.

(Here and in the following, $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm.)

Now that we are done with the boilerplate, let us restate Theorem 3:

> **Proposition 5.** Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{+}$. Then, $\sum\limits_{d\geq1} \sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)  =\left[ n=1\right]  $.

*Proof of Proposition 5.* Let $d\geq1$. Then, the sum $\sum
\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)  $ can be simplified as
follows, depending on whether $d\nmid n$ or $d\mid n$:

- If $d\nmid n$, then this sum $\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}
  }\mu\left(  d\right)  $ has no addends (since there exists no $s\geq1$
  satisfying $ds=n$), and thus simplifies to $0$.
- If $d\mid n$, then this sum $\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}
  }\mu\left(  d\right)  $ has exactly one addend (namely, the addend for
  $s=n/d$), and this addend is $\mu\left(  d\right)  $. Thus, if $d\mid n$, then
  this sum $\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)  $
  simplifies to $\mu\left(  d\right)  $.

Combining these two observations, we obtain

**(1)** $\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)  =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }d\nmid n;\\
\mu\left(  d\right)  , & \text{if }d\mid n
\end{cases}
$.

Now, forget that we fixed $d$. We thus have proven **(1)** for each $d\geq1$.
Summing the equality **(1)** up over all $d\geq1$, we obtain

$\sum\limits_{d\geq1}\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(
d\right)  =\sum\limits_{d\geq1}
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }d\nmid n;\\
\mu\left(  d\right)  , & \text{if }d\mid n
\end{cases}
$

$=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{d\geq1;\\d\mid n}}}_{=\sum\limits_{d\mid
n}}\underbrace{
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }d\nmid n;\\
\mu\left(  d\right)  , & \text{if }d\mid n
\end{cases}
}_{\substack{=\mu\left(  d\right)  \\\text{(since }d\mid n\text{)}}
}+\sum\limits_{\substack{d\geq1;\\d\nmid n}}\underbrace{
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }d\nmid n;\\
\mu\left(  d\right)  , & \text{if }d\mid n
\end{cases}
}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }d\nmid n\text{)}}}$

$=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu\left(  d\right)  +\underbrace{\sum
\limits_{\substack{d\geq1;\\d\nmid n}}0}_{=0}=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\mu\left(
d\right)  =\left[  n=1\right]  $ (by Theorem 3).

This proves Proposition 5.

Now, we can prove Theorem 2:

*Proof of Theorem 2.* For each integer $d\geq1$, we have

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  \underbrace{x^{dn}}_{=\left(
x^{d}\right)  ^{n}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  \left(
x^{d}\right)  ^{n}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-\left(
x^{d}\right)  ^{k}}$

(this follows from Theorem 1 by substituting $x^{d}$ for $x$)

$=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{dk}}=\prod\limits_{w=1}^{\infty
}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{dw}}$

(here, we have renamed the index $k$ as $w$ in the product). Taking logarithms on
both sides of this equality, we obtain

$\log\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  x^{dn}\right)
=\log\left(  \prod\limits_{w=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{dw}}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{w=1}^{\infty} \left(-\underbrace{\log\left(  1-x^{dw}\right)
}_{\substack{=-\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\dfrac{\left(  x^{dw}\right)  ^{s}}
{s}\\\text{(this follows from Theorem 4 by substituting }x^{dw}\text{ for
}x\text{)}}}\right)$

(since the logarithm takes products into sums, and takes quotients into differences)

$=\sum\limits_{w=1}^{\infty}-\left(  -\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\dfrac{\left(
x^{dw}\right)  ^{s}}{s}\right)  =\underbrace{\sum\limits_{w=1}^{\infty}
}_{=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\underbrace{\dfrac{\left(
x^{dw}\right)  ^{s}}{s}}_{=\dfrac{1}{s}x^{dws}}$

**(4)** $=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\dfrac{1}{s}x^{dws}$.

Since the logarithm takes products into sums and takes powers into multiples,
we have

$\log\left(  \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty
}p\left(  n\right)  x^{kn}\right)  ^{\mu\left(  k\right)  /k}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(  \mu\left(  k\right)  /k\right)
\log\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  x^{kn}\right)  $

$=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{d=1}^{\infty}}_{=\sum\limits_{d\geq1}}\left(
\mu\left(  d\right)  /d\right)  \underbrace{\log\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}
^{\infty}p\left(  n\right)  x^{dn}\right)  }_{\substack{=\sum\limits_{w\geq
1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\dfrac{1}{s}x^{dws}\\\text{(by (4))}}}$

(here, we have renamed the summation index $k$ as $d$ in the outer sum)

$=\sum\limits_{d\geq1}\left(  \mu\left(  d\right)  /d\right)  \sum
\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\dfrac{1}{s}x^{dws}$

$=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{d\geq1}\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}
}_{=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\sum\limits_{d\geq1}
}\underbrace{\left(  \mu\left(  d\right)  /d\right)  \cdot\dfrac{1}{s}}
_{=\mu\left(  d\right)  /\left(  ds\right)  }\underbrace{x^{dws}}_{=x^{dsw}}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\underbrace{\sum\limits_{d\geq1}
\mu\left(  d\right)  /\left(  ds\right)  \cdot x^{dsw}}_{\substack{=\sum
\limits_{n\geq1}\sum\limits_{\substack{d\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)
/\left(  ds\right)  \cdot x^{dsw}\\\text{(since each }d\geq1\text{ satisfies
}ds=n\\\text{for a unique }n\geq1\text{)}}}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\underbrace{\sum\limits_{s\geq1}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}
\sum\limits_{\substack{d\geq1;\\ds=n}}}_{=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\sum
\limits_{d\geq1}\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}}\mu\left(  d\right)
/\left(  \underbrace{ds}_{=n}\right)  \cdot\underbrace{x^{dsw}}
_{\substack{=x^{nw}\\\text{(since }ds=n\text{)}}}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\sum\limits_{d\geq1}\sum
\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)  /n\cdot x^{nw}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\dfrac{1}{n}\underbrace{\sum
\limits_{d\geq1}\sum\limits_{\substack{s\geq1;\\ds=n}}\mu\left(  d\right)
}_{\substack{=\left[  n=1\right]  \\\text{(by Proposition 5)}}}\cdot x^{nw}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\dfrac{1}{n}\left[
n=1\right]  \cdot x^{nw}}_{=\dfrac{1}{1}\left[  1=1\right]  \cdot x^{1w}
+\sum\limits_{n\geq2}\dfrac{1}{n}\left[  n=1\right]  \cdot x^{nw}}$

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\left(  \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{1}}_{=1}
\underbrace{\left[  1=1\right]  }_{=1}\cdot\underbrace{x^{1w}}_{=x^{w}}
+\sum\limits_{n\geq2}\dfrac{1}{n}\underbrace{\left[  n=1\right]
}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since }n\neq1\\\text{(since }n\geq2\text{))}}}\cdot
x^{nw}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq1}\left(  x^{w}+\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n\geq2}\dfrac
{1}{n}0\cdot x^{nw}}_{=0}\right)  =\sum\limits_{w\geq1}x^{w}=\sum
\limits_{w\geq0}\underbrace{x^{w+1}}_{=xx^{w}}$

(here, we have substituted $w+1$ for $w$ in the sum)

$=\sum\limits_{w\geq0}xx^{w}=x\underbrace{\sum\limits_{w\geq0}x^{w}}
_{=\dfrac{1}{1-x}}=x\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\dfrac{x}{1-x}$.

Taking the exponential on both sides of this equality, we obtain

$\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}p\left(
n\right)  x^{kn}\right)  ^{\mu\left(  k\right)  /k}=\exp\dfrac{x}{1-x}$.

Theorem 2 is proven.

Comment: Many thanks for share your detailed calculations with all us. Thank you very much, now it will be a very good reference for all. I am going to study your nice answer.